# best way of adding blog to existing website - Can you apply layout from the root directory to blog in sub-directory?

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, blogs, ghost

I am building a website using Bootstrap Frameworks for a friend and they would like a blog that they can easily update.

I don't like wordpress that much but appreciate it is easy for website owners to update themselves etc and am thinking of adding a wordpress or Ghost blog to the bootstrap website I am building.

**Some Problem**

1. I would like the style of the blog to match exactly that of the rest of the website which is built using bootstrap and less. I am confused as to the best and most appropriate way of doing this
2. I dont want lots of plug ins which slow websites (particularly wp websites) down so am leaning towards ghost as it is exactly what I need; a blog.
3. Many wp themes are built so badly when it comes to SEO, not making use of header tags properly and making it difficult to change the page titles (eg many themes insert your company name into the page titles with a "-" and it is time consuming and confusing with little wp experience to change things like thiis)

**The main Question**

If I wanted to use Ghost say, and made a ghost blog which I put in a sub-folder (i.e mysite.com/blog), would I be able to apply my existing custom built bootstrap theme from the root folder to a sub-folder where the ghost blog lives (i.e some php to "include" header, footer etc and css still being applied to this subfolder) or would I have to have the bootstrap files in the new sub-folder too and re-code a navbar, header and footer etc to match that of the existing website?

Sorry if this is a rather stupid question but I haven't added a blog to an existing website before and am rather new-ish to this

What I don't want is to have to update my friends blog for him every-time he wants to post something new!

I understand this question could be seen as subjective which is why I have listed the problems I may find with it, so that answers can be in response to these kind of problems and questions. I hope this is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to try ghost to build your blog. There is a feature to add team members which can help your friend update the blog himself. There are many free themes. The installation is well documented, flexible and easy to use once deployed. https://ghost.org/developers/

Comment: Great thanks, would I be able to apply my layout from the root (which I have built myself using bootstrap) to the ghost blog in a subfolder? Or would I have to add the bootstrap files and code it all again in the sub-directory? Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You should be able to apply your layout to ghost. If i have understood your question, this link might help answer your question better: https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-ghost/

Comment: Great thanks will check it out - yes I mean using bootstrap with it and as it will be in a subfolder of an existing website built in bootstrap surely I can use php to "include" the header and footer and it is in the root? Sorry if this sounds stupid I haven't added a blog before, I get you can do this with wp but not as much docs on ghost!